cmake stuck at "Performing Test HAVE_FFI_CALL" when running inside a ntfs drive on Arch Linux
I have a simple C++ project where I am using CMake for generating the Makefiles. I observed, if my project is stored in a ntfs drive, that on running
cmake ..

from the build dir, cmake is stuck at
-- Performing Test HAVE_FFI_CALL

Below is the complete message from cmake:
cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 14.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 14.2.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test HAVE_FFI_CALL

CMake works properly when doing the same from my home dir which is of type ext4. It was working till 2 days back on ntfs drive, but not any more. Any help?

My OS: Arch Linux
CMake version: 3.31.1

